# how to disable select with condition on value from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

How to disabled select "pelajaran" where condition select jabatan = "operator"

```
<select name="id_jabatan" id="jabatan" size="1" class="form-control"  required>
    <option label="-- Pilih Jabatan --"></option>
    <?php //query untuk looping jabatan
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_jabatan_guru";
        $result = $koneksi->query($sql);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['idJabatan'] ?>"><?php echo $row['namaJabatan']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>


<select name="id_pel" id="pelajaran" size="1" class="form-control" disabled required>
    <option label="-- Pilih Pelajaran --"></option>
    <?php //query untuk looping pelajaran
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_pelajaran";
        $result = $koneksi->query($sql);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['idPelajaran'] ?>"><?php echo $row['namaPelajaran']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>


<script>
    document.getElementById('jabatan').onchange = function () {
        document.getElementById("pelajaran").disabled = this.value == 'Operator';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: On page load right? (not dynamically selected)

Comment: Code should be in the question - not on an external resource (e.g. Pastebin) ... what happens if Pastebin goes away?

Comment: The JavaScript code you have written looks like it should do what you want? What is the problem?

Comment: On a side note, perhaps take this code to codereview.stackexchange.com for advice on how to improve this code. As it is at the moment it is going to cause problems the more you build on it.

Comment: **solved**

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check it,

```
document.getElementById('jabatan').onchange = function () {
    if(this.value == 'Operator'){
       document.getElementById('pelajaran').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hello Fahruddin Yusuf Habibi

i'm going to show you the way it work for me. i hope it does for you too. my code was like this:

```
<select onChange="showSelect();" name="id_jabatan" id="jabatan" size="1" class="form-control"  required>
</select>

<div id="selectDisable" style="display:none">
<select name="id_pel" id="pelajaran" size="1" class="form-control" disabled required>
</select>
</div>

<script>
function showSelect(){
var value = document.getElementbyId('jabatan'); 
    if(value == 'Operator'){
    document.getElementbyId('selectDisable').style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
    document.getElementbyId('selectDisable').style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

As you can see this code it's realy easy, i called the function in a event on the select 'jabatan' and i put the select 'pelajaran' inside a 'div' with style display "none". when the function is called it gets the value selected and  if the value is 'Operator' it won't change the style... but if the value is another one it will change the style to block to make the 'div' visible.

i hope it help you. bye!